# imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not being called

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying for the first time to use an external library, [WDImagePicker](https://github.com/justwudi/WDImagePicker).  Below is the WDImagePicker code relevant to my problem.

```
@objc public protocol WDImagePickerDelegate {
    @objc optional func imagePicker(imagePicker: WDImagePicker, pickedImage: UIImage)
    @objc optional func imagePickerDidCancel(imagePicker: WDImagePicker)
}

@objc public class WDImagePicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, WDImageCropControllerDelegate {
    public var delegate: WDImagePickerDelegate?

    private var _imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController!

    public var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {
        return _imagePickerController
    }

    override public init() {
        super.init()
        self.cropSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 320)
        _imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        _imagePickerController.delegate = self
        _imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }

    public func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("this line never runs\n\n")
    }
}
```

In the controller I wrote myself, I have this method, which presents cropImagePicker's imagePickerContoller; however even though the delegate of this controller is cropImagePicker, cropImagePicker's ImagePickerControllerDelegate methods never get called (I tested all of them).

```
@IBAction func cameraButtonPressed() {
    let cropImagePicker = WDImagePicker()
    cropImagePicker.cropSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    cropImagePicker.delegate = self
    cropImagePicker.resizableCropArea = false
    cropImagePicker.imagePickerController.delegate = cropImagePicker
    self.present(cropImagePicker.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Why is this happening?  Could it be because of the swift 3 changes I had to make to the library?  And most importantly, how can I get around this? All input is appreciated.

Comment: there are many questions that have same name as yours, have you checked them?

Comment: Yeah, this one is very niche

Comment: "Could it be because of the swift 3 changes I had to make to the library?" Yes it might be, note that the latest commit is 7 months ago, I don't think they updated it -yet- to be compatible with Swift 3.

Comment: Well if I could just get this one piece of code to run I think I could hack through it.  The Image picker controller is being presented as intended, I just need the delegate methods to be called on the WD class